# Parsing an 8 bit char array to integer

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino and all I want to do is parse a String of binary numbers to an exact integer representation.

```cpp
char* byte1 = "11111111"
int binary1 = atoi(byte1);
Serial.print(binary1);
```

However this prints out: -19961

Can anyone explain why? I am coming from a Java and JavaScript perspective.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/Gu0OSc.

Comment: @DimChtz: that's normal, on Arduino `int` is 16 bit, while on ideone stuff runs on some 32 or 64 bit Linux machine.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yeah, you right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get  -19961 because on Arduino `int` is 16 bit wide and cannot hold any number bigger than 32767. To hold an integer representation of 11111111 you have to use `long` (which on Arduino is 32 bit) and `strtol`.

```
long val = strtol(byte1, NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` converts a decimal (base 10) string to int.  If you want to convert a binary string to int, you can use `strtol`:

```
char *byte1 = "11111111";
int val1 = strtol(byte1, 0, 2);
std::cout << val1 << std::endl;
```

`strtol` can convert any base -- the 3rd argument is the base to use.

Comment: I tried running and got 255 with this code: char* byte1 = "11111111";

        int binary1 = strtol(byte1,0,2);
          Serial.print(binary1)

Comment: Yes, that is correct -- binary 11111111 is decimal 255.  You're reading a binary number and printing it as decimal.

Comment: Oh okay. I just want to read the binary string "1111111" and get it to return the integer: 11111111

Comment: But the binary string "11111111" is the integer 255.  The integer 11111111 is the binary string "101010011000101011000111".  Which do you want?

Comment: Then you don't really want to read it as a binary string, but as a decimal string. In that case, you have to use `strtol` passing 10 as base, and assign the result to a `long` variable, as on Arduino `int` is 16 bit, so the maximum number it can hold is 32767.